# How to get user id by username (and not by name)

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

The [Instagram API documentation for user endpoint](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) mentions that searching for a user id is done by his/her name (*and not by username*).

For example:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=tag&client_id=[client_id] returns a lot of users named "Tag" but the search results do not include the user_id for the account: https://instagram.com/tag/

Similarly, the search at
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=cameron&client_id=[client_id] does not return the user_id for the account: https://instagram.com/cameron/

The only perfectly working solution I found online is: http://jelled.com/instagram/lookup-user-id

How do I get the user_id by username? *(Am I missing a query parameter or something??)*